# Is there a way to reduce rows number for a long period of time? Data decimation using timescale/postgresql

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

There is a table with a time series data which  holds a large amount of time series data - e.g. - each sensor generated data every 5 seconds, so there are a lot of rows with time and the speed of queries of course will decrease with the increase of of data inserted..

We need to reduce the data amount in the table, but not just delete the old data - we need to reduce detailed data - e.g. - save only data with time interval about 1 hour, not every 5 sec for each sensor for previous week/month.

But - I need not "averaged data for sensor". I need raw data, but decimated using predefined  time intervals - simple nearest by time points (e.g. from 5 sec interval - go to 1 min intervals between raws).

So I need to organize data decimation which will leave rows in table and reduce amount of data stored inside.
Is there a way to do it automatically by means of postgresql/timescale?

Added an example data and result.

Example - data in the table

```
row_id | datetime | sensor_id | sensor_data ...

1 | 2020-01-23 15:32:01.091421+02 | 1 | 2499
2 | 2020-01-23 15:32:06.091421+02 | 1 | 2498
3 | 2020-01-23 15:32:10.091421+02 | 1 | 2499
4 | 2020-01-23 15:32:14.091421+02 | 1 | 2497
5 | 2020-01-23 15:32:18.091421+02 | 1 | 2497
...
21 | 2020-01-23 15:33:01.091421+02 | 1 | 2493
22 | 2020-01-23 15:33:05.091421+02 | 1 | 2492
23 | 2020-01-23 15:33:09.091421+02 | 1 | 2492
...
40 | 2021-01-23 15:34:16.091421+02 | 1 | 2487
41 | 2021-01-23 15:38:16.091421+02 | 1 | 2486
...
1892039 | 2021-01-23 15:33:05.091421+02 | 1 | 3456
1892040 | 2021-01-23 15:33:09.091421+02 | 1 | 3456
1892041 | 2021-01-23 15:33:13.091421+02 | 1 | 3457
```

So I need to keep the newest data with the same granularity for current month (for example - every 4 seconds), but with the data older then 1 month - I need to save only data with 1 minute granularity (not averaged, e.g. - first data in a minute interval)..
According to this example it will be only

```
row_id | datetime | sensor_id | sensor_data ...

1 | 2020-01-23 15:32:01.091421+02 | 1 | 2499
21 | 2020-01-23 15:33:01.091421+02 | 1 | 2493
40 | 2021-01-23 15:34:16.091421+02 | 1 | 2487
1892039 | 2021-01-23 15:33:05.091421+02 | 1 | 3456
1892040 | 2021-01-23 15:33:09.091421+02 | 1 | 3456
1892041 | 2021-01-23 15:33:13.091421+02 | 1 | 3457
```

Comment: you can use Continuous Aggregates (https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/data-retention). and use FIRST_VALUE OVER  ...

Comment: Can you give an example of the behavior? 2-3 sets of rows reduced 2-3 rows. It will help to propose a solution. IMHO using [continuous aggregates](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#continuous-aggregates) should help, just requires to chose suitable aggregate functions and grouping.

Comment: just added some data for illustration